# Canvas toDataURL in IE11 security error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to convert svg to image data url
first i converted svg to canvas, now canvas to dataurl giving security error in IE11
and tried to convert canvas to msToBlob also same error in IE11
is there any workaround for IE11
its working in other browser

Comment: Nope no workaround for complex svg images. They fixed it in in Edge though. And for simple svgs you can use a library like canvg which will convert your svg elements to canvas drawings.

Comment: i also tried canvg, it working in other browsers but in IE11 Access dined at svg.ajax from canvg.js

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I was also facing same issue for IE11.

After searching so much I came to know about [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg), which is really good and easy solution.

And canvg specially mentioned this scenario as well in their usage list.

**Allows for SVG -> Canvas -> png transition all on the client side (through toDataUrl)**

```
var imageURL = '<svg xmlns.....></svg>';
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");


    canvg(c, imageURL,{
     renderCallback:
        function()
        {
            console.log(c.toDataURL('image/png'));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question seems to be pretty old, I want to give an answer to this so that it may help someone.

First convert the svg elements to a canvas using **Fabric.js.** Then use html2canvas to convert the canvas to image.[Fabric is pretty good one, converts any sort of svg to canvas without any issues. Fabric helps in places where canvg doesn't help.